# Adding a Spring Data Repository disables functionality

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have these two entities.

```
@Entity
public class Person {

@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String name;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Location location;

public Person() {

}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Location {

@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String place;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "location")
private Set<Person> persons;


public Location() {

}
```

I also have this Controller.

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

private final PersonRepository repo;

public PersonController(PersonRepository repo) {
    this.repo = repo;
}

@GetMapping("/")
public String newPerson(Person person){
    return "home";

}

@PostMapping("/")
public String newPerson(Person person, BindingResult result){   
    repo.save(person);
    return "redirect:/person";
}
```

And this Repository.

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

Optional<Person> findFirstByName(String name);

}
```

I also have this backing form.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${person}" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Location:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{location}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

This all works fine when I submit some data. A Person object is saved and so is a Location object.

But when I add

```
@Repository
public interface LocationRepository extends JpaRepository<Location, 
Long> {)
```

the Location object does not save to the database when I submit the same exact form. Why would just adding this repository cause this issue and what is the solution? Thanks.

Comment: can you try `th:field="*{location.place}" ` ?

Comment: Thanks. That did fix the problem. I thought it was something small that I was missing out on. Still kind of wondering why the form would work without the LocationRepository? I'm guessing because when the repository is created the Location object expects an id to be passed perhaps.

Comment: repositories aren't required when you fill in the form, they are used to store data

Comment: I know that, it's just slightly confusing as to why `th:field="*{location}"` saved to the database, but once I added the LocationRepository, it would not save the Location to the database, and required your fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You whould fix your form in order to write attribute of location property:

```
<td><input type="text" th:field="*{location.place}" /></td>
```

Also you don't have to put `@Repository` annotation on your repositories.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on why things work as they work:

The form binding uses the `ConversionService`. Spring Data registers a conversion chain from `String` -> id type -> entity type for each repository managed domain class. So the moment you add a repository, the  `String` submitted as value for `Person.location` will be interpreted as an identifier for an already existing location. It will cause a by-id lookup with the value submitted for the field named `location`.

This is handy in the following scenario: assume you're `Location` is basically a curated list of instances held in the database, e.g. a list of countries. They you don't want to arbitrarily create new ones but rather select one from the overall list, which basically boils down to having to use a dropdown box instead of a text field.

So conceptually, the fundamental things at odds are the cascades (as they indicate a composition, i.e. `Location` being part of the aggregate) and the existence of `LocationRepository` as a repository causes the managed type to implicitly becoming an aggregate root (which is fundamental DDD).

This in turn means you have to handle the lifecycle of that instance separately. A potential solution is to inspect the `Location` bound to the `Person`, check whether an instance with that `place` already exists (via a query method on `LocationRepository`) and if so, replace the one bound with the one loaded or just call `LocationRepository.save(…)` with the original instance to create a new one.

I still don't totally buy that the original attempt created a *correct* `Location` as from your template Spring Framework is not able to guess that what you submit as `location` is supposed to be the `place` actually. So I assume you saw a `Location` instance being created, but completely empty and the `BindingResult` actually carrying an error, claiming it couldn't transform the `location` form field into an instance of `Location`.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the response. But I did just try the example again with no `LocationRepository` and with just `th:field="*{location}"` on the form and it did in fact work. I'm looking at the database in MySQL and there is in fact a `Person` object being saved to a person table with a foreign key to a `Location` object in a location table. Try it out.